# How to get date ranges according to date data inside database table

Tags: sql-server

I have a #TMP table filled with dates with its corresponding remarks. It looks like this:

```
Date         isworkdays   isweekdays   
2019-08-16   1            1
2019-08-17   0            0
2019-08-18   0            0
2019-08-19   1            1
2019-08-20   1            1
2019-08-21   1            1
2019-08-22   1            1
2019-08-23   1            1
2019-08-24   0            0
2019-08-25   0            0
2019-08-26   1            1
2019-08-27   1            1
2019-08-28   1            1
2019-08-29   1            1
2019-08-30   1            1
2019-08-31   0            0
2019-09-01   0            0
2019-09-02   1            1
2019-09-03   1            1
2019-09-04   1            1
2019-09-05   1            1
2019-09-06   1            1
2019-09-07   0            0
2019-09-08   0            0
2019-09-09   1            1
2019-09-10   1            1
2019-09-11   1            1
2019-09-12   1            1
2019-09-13   1            1
2019-09-14   0            0
2019-09-15   0            0
2019-09-16   1            1
2019-09-17   1            1
2019-09-18   1            1
2019-09-19   1            1
2019-09-20   1            1
2019-09-21   0            0
2019-09-22   0            0
2019-09-23   1            1
2019-09-24   1            1
2019-09-25   1            1
2019-09-26   1            1
2019-09-27   1            1
2019-09-28   0            0
2019-09-29   0            0
2019-09-30   1            1
```

`Date` column are obviously a series of dates from `2019-08-16` to `2019-10-16`
`isworkingdays` column indicates "1" if the date is from Monday to Friday, and "0" if its Saturday and Sunday. `isweekdays` column indicates "1" if the date is not holiday and "0" if its holiday.

I want to count the days betweem 2019-08-16 to 2019-09-16 only to those dates with isworkdays = 1, and for Saturday and Sunday count it as 1

This is what I have done so far

```
declare @userinput date
SELECT SUM(IsWorkDay) AS DayCount FROM AMIFIN..PDC T
 LEFT JOIN dbo.#TMP c ON c.[Date] <= T.Check_Date 
WHERE CAST(@userinput AS Date) <= CAST((c.[Date]) as date) AND c.IsWorkDay = 1
```

but it returns 3952743 days

Comment: `and for saturday and sunday count it as 1` ... what does this actually mean?  Can you show sample output based on a date range contained with your given sample data?

Comment: for normal days like from mon - fri, it is counted as a 1, but for saturday and sunday instead of counting it individually it should be counted as 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. Thanks to all who posted an answer it gives me a lot of idea.

Here is my solution:

```
Declare @cnt INT = 0
DECLARE @postponedate date = cast('2019-08-20' as date); --Will be the current date of postponement
DECLARE @checkdate date = cast('2019-08-27' as date); --Date of the check
Declare @fdate date = (select [Date] FROM #TMP WHERE [Date] = @checkdate); --dates to be compared


WHILE @postponedate <= @fdate
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IsWorkDay INT = (select IsWorkDay FROM #TMP WHERE cast([Date] as date) = @postponedate)
    DECLARE @IsWeekDay INT = (select IsWeekDay FROM #TMP WHERE cast([Date] as date) = @postponedate)

        SET @cnt = CASE WHEN @IsWorkDay = 1 THEN
            @cnt + 1 
        ELSE
            @cnt + 0.5
        END

        SET @postponedate = DATEADD(Day, 1, @postponedate)

    PRINT @postponedate
    PRINT @cnt
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation should work here:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN isworkdays = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0.5 END) AS DayCount
FROM AMIFIN..PDC T
LEFT JOIN dbo.#TMP c
    ON c.[Date] <= T.Check_Date 
WHERE
    @userinput < c.[Date];
```

This idea here is to count 1 for a weekday, and 1/2 for a weekend day.  The half counting logic is necessary, because it could be that we end up counting an odd number of weekend days.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query will be like this:

```
 SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, date, date) + 1) AS Total
    FROM tbl_TMP
    WHERE date >= '2019-08-16' AND date <= '2019-09-30'
    AND isworkdays=1 AND isweekdays=1
    GROUP BY isworkdays,isweekdays
```

Note: "+1" because `DATEDIFF` returns No. of days in `INT` DataType